# Storing entities sharing common properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am newbie in Mongodb.

Currently I am working on a project using MEAN stack. I am using schema less orientation for storing data i.e mongodb as client and not mongoose.

After my research from internet I found that schema less database performs(speed) well when compared to schema based nosql database and hence decided for schema less approach.

Scenario I am facing:

I have few entities that share common properties. Say for Entity A has name,location,phone no and Entity B has additional properties in common with those properties from that of A.

Suppose considering my application will scale upto 1 billion users

Question for the above scenario discussed

```
1) Is it better to store as different collection for different types 
   or prefer inheritance type of approach for storing those entities.
   If inheritance type is preferred how it is done in mongodb.
```

Few other general questions(considering large scalability)

```
1) Is my schema less approach right choice 
2) Is it better to use ODM tool or directly write code in my dao 
   layer to access the database without using object approach
```

Many may feel that this is totally out of scope from mongodb, I am asking this question basically from design and performance perspective.

So need advice from experts who has really worked on large scale application development using mongodb.

Comment: I don't think there is a right answer to some of your questions. This might be helpful: [Why do we need, what advantages to use mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18531821/1022914). Mongoose also offers [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) for schema inheritance.

Comment: @Mikey.  Thanks for the response. Will go through the link you have mentioned